# Git remote origin incorrect after clone

Tags: git, ssh

I have a Git repository on a Media Temple server at: `http://git.mywebsite.com/example.git`

If I do a clone of this repo and then look inside the config file I get the following:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://git.mywebsite.com/example.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

The problem is that I use SSH to commit and push the changes back up the Media Temple server repo... in other words, the url isn't the same as the one I pulled it down from, so if I look inside another working copy I have to have the following inside the config file for it to work:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://mywebsite.com@s00000.gridserver.com/home/00000/domains/git.mywebsite.com/html/example.git
```

**I also have this same line in the config on the server so was hoping it would get pulled down to new clones (but it doesn't)**

So the question is, how can I allow a user to clone a repo and then make changes and commit WITHOUT having to change the remote origin AFTER, or even having to add the SSH url?? i.e. it's already there by default when they clone.

As like I stated above, I declared it in the config file on the server, but it gets overridden when I make a new clone of the repo. **Note: Even if I called the remote different on the server .e.g grid, it would still get removed and replaced by where the repo was downloaded from.**

Comment: What was the exact command you used to clone the repo?

Comment: `git clone http://git.mywebsite.com/example.git` but this isn't the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://git.mywebsite.com/example.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

was created while cloning using this URL. You cloned from the origin. You can change it as you described, so your local repository will forget that it had this origin and will use the new origin, with the other URL.

I suggest to use more than one remote:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://git.mywebsite.com/example.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "cameronsotherremote"]
    url = ssh://mywebsite.com@s00000.gridserver.com/home/00000/domains/git.mywebsite.com/html/example.git
    ...
```

Then you are able to work with these two "locations" without changing the config file again and again. But you have to do it once.

Comment: Yeah the user STILL has to add `camersonotherremote` AFTER the clone has happened in order to push changes. I want to make it so that this already exists when a user clones the repo.

Comment: Or is possible to make it appear by default? Thanks,

Comment: Not with git only. You could create a programm/script which starts the clone and changes the configuration automatically afterwards in the way descibed by @torek, me or in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: you can't always get what you want (imagine appropriate music here) :-)

The only way to deliver the alternate URL to someone cloning the repository is to make the alternate URL part of the repository itself, e.g., a file stored in a commit (perhaps under a special branch).

You can, however, set this alternate URL as the "push url" for the existing "remote" origin:

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl ssh://...
```

Put the command in a file, commit the file (again perhaps on a "special" branch, maybe even in a commit graph segment that is not connected to `master` at all), and after cloning, check out and run the file.  This is also a decent way to deliver hooks that you'd like people to use (since git hooks, like other configuration data, are not copied on clone).

Comment: But that will still require the user who has cloned the repo to run the command BEFORE they can commit their changes... right?

Comment: Yes, hence "can't always get what you want": git won't clone things that aren't part of the repo itself, and configured URLs are not part of the repo itself.